# VIM: Move lines of code left side with %s?

Tags: vim

When we want to move line 2 to 50 one tab we use in VIM/vi editor

```
:2,50 s/^/^I
```

Instead of one tab, how do we move lines of code one back backward, on the left side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have real tabs in your file, the literal reverse of your code is

```
:2,50 s/^^I/
```

(the first `^` is real <kbd>^</kbd>; the following `^I` is typed using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> sequence.

You could also use

```
:2,50norm <<
```

which should unindent both tabs and spaces, assuming correctly set up tab settings; or, equivalently, go to visual mode and select lines you want, and just `<<`. The indent equivalent is `>>`. I would not normally use `:s` to indent or unindent code, always `>`, `<` or `=`.

Comment: Instead of typing `^I` (as Ctrl-V Ctrl-I as stated in this answer), you can also perfectly type `\t` in `:2,50s/^\t/`.

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel: Oh, yeah; it's just that in the first part of the answer I'm making the perfect mirror of the OP's indenting code.